# Using dynamic sql in a procedure to insert data into schema tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I hope that you are all doing well.

I've been working on a project where I need to store data about my college that includes ID numbers, names, contact details etc.

I'm having a bit of difficulty in creating a stored procedure that will be able to insert data into a specified schema.table_name. The procedure must be able to allow the EXEC command to specify which schema you would like the insert data into. The table_name will stay the same for all the 14 schemas. The following code sample is what I have come up with but it doesn't seem to work:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddStudent_proc(@campus varchar(50), @StudentID numeric(4,0), @Name varchar(50), @Surname varchar(50), @ID_numeric numeric(13,0), @Address varchar(100))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @dynamic varchar(MAX)
    SET @dynamic = 'INSERT INTO ['+quotename(@campus)+'].Student_tbl(
    StudentID,
    Name,
    Surname,
    ID_numeric,
    Address
    )
    VALUES('+quotename(@StudentID)+','+quotename(@Name)+','+quotename(@Surname)+','+quotename(@ID_numeric)+','+quotename(@Address)+');'
    EXEC (@dynamic);
END
GO
```

My entire structure can be found
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55169997/using-dynamic-sql-in-a-procedure-to-create-schemas-and-tables)

I'd appreciate any help on this topic as I am still quite new to SQL as a whole.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will need to make proper quotations in your dynamic query. I always select the statement before the execution.  Select @dynamic --> EXEC (@dynamic) to figure out what's wrong. Each level needs to double the quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use [`quotename`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for data - as the name of the function implies, it should be used with names (A.K.A identifiers).
Also, when you are using `quotename` it addeds `[` and `]` around the value it receives, so no point of adding them again (`['+quotename(@campus)+']` in your code).

I would recommend three improvements to the procedure you have now:

1. Change the data type of `@campus` to [`sysname`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) - this is a special data type synonym to `nvarchar(128) not null` used by SQL Server for all identifiers.
2. white-list the schema name.
   This is a critical change to protect against SQL Injection attacks.
   Anything that can't be parameterized needs to be white-listed.
3. use [`sp_ExecuteSql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) instead of `EXEC`

This will result in a better stored procedure because it eliminates the threat of [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

I've written a couple of blog posts that adds some more information and background on this subject: [The do’s and don’ts of dynamic SQL for SQL Server](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/09/12/the-does-and-donts-of-dynamic-sql-for-sql-server/) and [Back to basics: SQL Injection](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2020/07/16/back-to-basics-sql-injection/).

Anyway, here's how I would write this procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddStudent_proc(
    @campus sysname, 
    @StudentID numeric(4,0), 
    @Name varchar(50), 
    @Surname varchar(50), 
    @ID_numeric numeric(13,0), 
    @Address varchar(100)
)
AS
BEGIN

    IF EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM Sys.Schemas
        WHERE name = @campus
    )
    BEGIN

    DECLARE @dynamic nvarchar(4000), 
            @paramDefinition nvarchar(4000)


        SELECT @dynamic = N'INSERT INTO '+ quotename(@campus) + N'.Student_tbl (
            StudentID,
            Name,
            Surname,
            ID_numeric,
            Address
        )
        VALUES(@StudentID, @Name, @Surname, @ID_numeric, @Address)',
        @paramDefinition = 
          N'@StudentID numeric(4,0), 
            @Name varchar(50), 
            @Surname varchar(50), 
            @ID_numeric numeric(13,0), 
            @Address varchar(100)'

        EXEC sp_executeSql @dynamic, @paramDefinition, @StudentID, @Name, @Surname, @ID_numeric, @Address;
    END
END
GO
```

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly as expected. Just a quick question for learning purposes, what is the use of the " N' " before the INSERT INTO?

Comment: Read [Why do we need to put N before strings in Microsoft SQL Server?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/155859/why-do-we-need-to-put-n-before-strings-in-microsoft-sql-server)

Comment: Thanks again. Very helpful.

Comment: I've edited my answer with one more change - not extremely significant but good to know. Glad to help :-)

Comment: @ZoharPeled: I'd recommend specifying that Step 2 prevents SQL injection. I've worked with many developers who think that sp_executesql and quotename somehow prevent injection.

Comment: Actually it's the combination of both... - you white list what you can't parameterize.

Comment: @dylanthelion Added a clarification as recommended. It might not be as obvious as I initially thought.

Comment: @ZoharPeled: I am aware. Perhaps just personal experience, but I can't count the number of times a dev has seen a blog or SO post that doesn't explain injection flaws in detail, and decided that DECLARE @ SQL = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @ Table; sp_executesql @ SQL is okay. Also, nice update. It encompasses everything.